# Mutiple embedded mail applications or select from config

Tags: php, email

I am developing a beginners application to signup, login, verify, and authenticate users to my site in PHP. My main domain is hosted by GoDaddy who proscribe the use of PHPMailer and effectively force the use of PHP Mail function. I am also using NetBeans 8.2 to be my development vehicle.
I need advice as to which way I should proceed.

Option A.

Where the PHP requires emails sent to the user's address such as during signup to permit them to authenticate their ownership of the email address. Should I include in the code the two possibilities using '$host = **HOST**;'
and then have two threads depending on whether the answer is 'localhost' or 
domain.name and then send the mail.

Option B.

Where the PHP requires emails sent it refers to the $host to select the appropriate code to send the mail from a different include.

I need advice from expert PHP practioners?

Comment: you might want to research the Dependency Injection pattern

Comment: While I appreciate the pointer to a modern? way of approaching the problem it does not answer the question just poses more questions.

Comment: that's why I commented rather than answering. Your option B is actually describing something that's close to dependency injection, but not in the way it's normally done. I'm not sure how "modern" it is as a design pattern. The first page of google when you search for it returns pages more than 10 years old talking about how it's been growing in popularity for some time.